# Finding tags within tags in jquery and replacing content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four `article` tags in my html page with the class `col`. Inside each article I have a `div` with the class `heading`. Inside of that I have an `img` tag.

I'm trying to iterate through each artcle and remove that image tag and replace with some different html.

This in Wordpress, hence the funky jquery function wrapper.

Right now im just trying to get the finding and replacing working (below) - I haven't attempted the different code for each article bit yet. I can't figure out why the below doesn't work.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('article.col').each(function(el) {
      $((el).find('heading img').replaceWith('<newtag>somecode</newtag>'));  
    });
  });
 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Is it a typo or you forgot to close the el? $(el).find....?

Comment: Nope, it wasn't, i have added that back in- although it still calling the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `each`, the function value are `function(index, element)`. So right now, you are trying to search a number with `$(el)`, try `$(this)` or add an other argument to your function.

also, the dot is missing for the class `heading`

```
$('article.col').each(function(index, el) {
   $(el).find('.heading img').replaceWith('<newtag>somecode</newtag>');  
});
```

or

```
$('article.col').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.heading img').replaceWith('<newtag>somecode</newtag>');  
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked and found all the tags. I assume if I want a different newtag for each one it finds, I would use the index and pass in a number, so 0 for the first article it finds, 1 for seconds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('article.col').each(function(el) {
       $(this).find('heading img').replaceWith('<newtag>somecode</newtag>');  
   });
  });
 }(jQuery));
```

Btw, the jQuery wrapper is to prevent conflicts with other libraries using the $ symbol.

Comment: Thanks kcdwayne. I'm not getting any errors anymore, but its not doing anything. Am I searching for the tags correctly in that find statement, or is it just looking for the words "heading img"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the syntax,

```
$(el.find('heading img').replaceWith('<newtag>somecode</newtag>'));
```

should be

```
$(this).find('heading img').replaceWith('<newtag>somecode</newtag>');
```

see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5bEq7/1/

Comment: Sorry I did something dumb, edited to remove a superfluous $(..)